# Accessing HDF5 dataset efficiently with h5py

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I want to create a python dict where from two HDF5 datasets. I discovered that it is very slow but found that by first using slicing of the entire dataset, I get an enormous speedup. Can someone explain to me why there is this huge discrepancy in efficiency when using slicing operator?

Example script:

```py
import h5py
import numpy as np
import time

N = 100000
d1 = np.random.random(size=(N,))
d2 = np.array([b"dummy"] * N)

hf = h5py.File("data.h5", "w")
hf.create_dataset("ID", data=d1)
hf.create_dataset("name", data=d2)

start = time.time()
test_dict1 = dict(zip(hf["ID"], hf["name"]))
print(f"elapsed time: {time.time() - start}s")

start = time.time()
test_dict2 = dict(zip(hf["ID"][:], hf["name"][:]))
print(f"elapsed time: {time.time() - start}s")

print(test_dict1 == test_dict2)
```

This produces following output:

```
elapsed time: 8.5617s
elapsed time: 0.0250s
True
```

Comment: `zip` iterates.  `zip(hf["ID"], hf["name"])` calls `hf` N times (or actually N*2), fetching single values each time.  With `[:]`, the whole dataset is read and placed in a numpy array.  That is iteration on the arrays is faster.  Iteration on the list equivalents might even be better: `dict(zip(hf["ID"][:].tolist(), hf["name"][:].tolist()))`

Comment: As @hpaulj noted, the 1st method accesses the file 2*N times (once for each zipped item). The 2nd method only reads data 2 times (to read each dataset into an array). HDF5/h5py I/O performance depends on the # of reads/writes more than the amount of data read. So 2 big reads is much, much faster than 2*N tiny reads.