# Is there an efficient way to load 2D from a 3D dataset in h5py?

Tags: dataset, h5py

I am a graduate student researching MR to CT traslation.

I created **MR, CT, and MASK groups in h5py and saved 3D data for each patient in the form of a dataset in each group**.
And when **loading data **again, I implemented code to **access the dataset in each group and retrieve each slice (2D data) (code shared below)**
The reason why they were not stacked at once in the slice dimension is because the width and height are different for each patient, so they cannot be stacked at once.

However, not only does it use a lot of CPU, but it also takes time to load, so network training takes a long time.

**Is there a way to improve this code or improve the way data is stored and loaded?**
Thank you for taking the time to read.

```py
class dataset_synthRAD_FLY(Dataset):
    def __init__(
        self,
        data_dir: str,
        rand_crop: bool = False,
        misalign_x: float = 0.0,
        misalign_y: float = 0.0,
        degree: float = 0.0,
        motion_prob: float = 0.0,
        deform_prob: float = 0.0,
        aug: bool = False,
        reverse: bool = False,
        return_msk: bool = False,
        crop_size=256,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.rand_crop = rand_crop
        self.data_dir = data_dir
        
        # Each patient has a different number of slices        
        self.patient_keys = []
        with h5py.File(self.data_dir, 'r') as file:
            self.patient_keys = list(file['MR'].keys())
            self.slice_counts = [file['MR'][key].shape[-1] for key in self.patient_keys]
            self.cumulative_slice_counts = np.cumsum([0] + self.slice_counts)
        
        if return_msk:
            self.aug_func = Compose(
                [
                    RandFlipd(keys=["A", "B", "M"], prob=0.5, spatial_axis=[0, 1]),
                    RandRotate90d(keys=["A", "B", "M"], prob=0.5, spatial_axes=[0, 1]),
                ]
            )

        else:
            self.aug_func = Compose(
                [
                    RandFlipd(keys=["A", "B"], prob=0.5, spatial_axis=[0, 1]),
                    RandRotate90d(keys=["A", "B"], prob=0.5, spatial_axes=[0, 1]),
                ]
            )

        self.misalign_x = misalign_x
        self.misalign_y = misalign_y
        self.degree = degree
        self.motion_prob = motion_prob
        self.deform_prob = deform_prob
        self.aug = aug
        self.reverse = reverse
        self.return_msk = return_msk
        self.crop_size = crop_size

        self.h5file = h5py.File(self.data_dir, 'r') 
        os.environ["HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING"] = "TRUE"

    def __len__(self):
        os.environ["HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING"] = "TRUE"
        return self.cumulative_slice_counts[-1]

    def __del__(self): 
        self.h5file.close()
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        patient_idx = np.searchsorted(self.cumulative_slice_counts, idx+1) - 1
        slice_idx = idx - self.cumulative_slice_counts[patient_idx]
        patient_key = self.patient_keys[patient_idx]
        
        A = self.h5file["MR"][patient_key][..., slice_idx]
        if (
            self.deform_prob > 0
            and idx > 2
            and idx < self.__len__() - 2
            and np.random.rand() < self.deform_prob
        ):
            slice_idx_new = np.random.randint(slice_idx + 1, slice_idx + 2)
            A = self.h5file["MR"][patient_key][..., slice_idx]
            B = self.h5file["CT"][patient_key][..., slice_idx_new]
        else:
            B = self.h5file["CT"][patient_key][..., slice_idx]

        if self.return_msk:
            M = self.h5file["MASK"][patient_key][..., slice_idx]
            M = torch.from_numpy(M[None])

        A = A.astype(np.float32)
        B = B.astype(np.float32)

        A = torch.from_numpy(A[None])
        B = torch.from_numpy(B[None])

        # Create a dictionary for the data
        if self.return_msk:
            data_dict = {"A": A, "B": B, "M": M}
        else:
            data_dict = {"A": A, "B": B}

        # Apply the random flipping
        if self.aug:
            data_dict = self.aug_func(data_dict)

        A = data_dict["A"]
        A = convert_to_tensor(A)
        B = data_dict["B"]
        B = convert_to_tensor(B)

        if self.return_msk:
            M = data_dict["M"]
            M = convert_to_tensor(M)

        # Perform misalignment (Rigid)
        # First: translation
        if self.misalign_x == 0 and self.misalign_y == 0 and self.degree == 0:
            pass
        else:
            A, B = translate_images(A, B, self.misalign_x, self.misalign_y, self.degree)

        if np.random.rand() < self.motion_prob:
            if self.reverse:
                A = motion_artifact(A)  # A is the label
            else:
                B = motion_artifact(B)  # B is the label

        A, B = torch.clamp(A, min=-1, max=1), torch.clamp(
            B, min=-1, max=1
        )  # make sure -1, 1
        
        if self.rand_crop:
            if self.return_msk:
                A, B, M = random_crop2(A, B, M, (self.crop_size, self.crop_size))

            else:
                A, B = random_crop(A, B, (self.crop_size, self.crop_size))

        if self.reverse:
            if self.return_msk:
                return B, A, M
            else:
                return B, A
        else:
            if self.return_msk:
                return A, B, M
            else:
                return A, B
```

- Write code as much as possible in the dataset's init.
- Do not use gzip when saving as h5. To make it faster when loading.

Comment: `h5` access is from a file, not RAM.  So slices that require reading widely separated parts of the file will be slow.  The h5py  docs warn about performance this kind of performance degradation.

Comment: Some recwnt SO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76680775/accessing-hdf5-dataset-efficiently-with-h5py, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77227983/what-is-the-fastest-way-read-slice-from-hdf5-dataset-using-h5py,

Comment: Since you probably read more often than write, it may make sense to store a transposed version of the file before processing. Make the slice the outermost index. Either that or rewrite the file as it is but with one chunk per slice. The first option will be faster and have fewer gotchas

Comment: If I understand your process, you are calling `__get_item__` once for each slice of each patient. So, if you have 500 slices, you 500 calls to read. As noted in 1 of the links @hpaulj provided, I/O performance depends on # of operations (in addition to chunking and slice shape). It would be MUCH FASTER to read the entire dataset into an array, then read array slices in memory.)

Comment: Note: you have this line twice: `A = self.h5file["MR"][patient_key][..., slice_idx]`. Deleting the repeated line inside the `if():` block will reduce the read I/Os. (Or maybe you forgot to change `slice_idx` to `slice_idx_new`?)

Answer (score 0):

Code below demonstrates differences in I/O performance with 3 methods that read slices of an HDF5 dataset to a NumPy array. Methods are:

1. Read image array slices from unchunked dataset (method in OP)
2. Read entire unchunked dataset to array, then read image array slices (method in my
   comment)
3. Read image array slices from chunked dataset

Method 3 is the same read process as Method 1, but the dataset must be created with chunked storage. The chunk shape matches 1 image slice: `(img_x,img_y,1)`.

Timing results show Method 2 and 3 are both significantly faster than Method 1. Method 2 is 20x faster, and Method 3 is 11x faster.

**Timing data**

1. Read array slices from UNCHUNCKED dataset: 16.53 sec
2. Read UNCHUNCKED dataset to array, then slice: 0.81 sec
3. Read read array slices from CHUNCKED dataset: 1.52 sec

**Code**
This below builds the example HDF5, then reads using 3 methods above. It creates a 2.4 GB file. You can adjust variables at the top if you want larger (or smaller) test files.

```
n_patients = 100
img_x, img_y = 256, 256
n_slices = 25

# Create file with 2 groups: MR1 unchunked datasets and MR2 chunked datasets
start = time.time()
with h5py.File('SO_77378615.h5','w') as h5f: 
    mr_grp1 = h5f.create_group('MR1')
    mr_grp2 = h5f.create_group('MR2')
    for i in range(1,n_patients+1):
        patient = f'patient_{i:03}'
        img_arr = np.random.random(img_x*img_y*n_slices).reshape(img_x,img_y,n_slices)
        mr_grp1.create_dataset(patient,data=img_arr)
        mr_grp2.create_dataset(patient,data=img_arr,chunks=(img_x,img_y,1))
print(f'time to create file with 2 datasets: {time.time()-start:.03f}')
                
# Open file and read all patient data
with h5py.File('SO_77378615.h5') as h5f:
     mr_grp1 = h5f['MR1'] # creates MR group object for reference
     start = time.time()
     for patient in mr_grp1:
         for slice in range(mr_grp1[patient].shape[2]):
             arr = mr_grp1[patient][:,:,slice]
     print(f'time to read array slices from UNCHUNCKED dataset: {time.time()-start:.03f}')

     start = time.time()
     for patient in mr_grp1:
         pat_arr = mr_grp1[patient][()]
         for slice in range(pat_arr.shape[2]):
                 arr = pat_arr[:,:,slice]
     print(f'time to read UNCHUNCKED dataset to array, then slice: {time.time()-start:.03f}')

     mr_grp2 = h5f['MR2'] # creates MR group object for reference
     start = time.time()
     for patient in mr_grp2:
         for slice in range(mr_grp2[patient].shape[2]):
             arr = mr_grp2[patient][:,:,slice]
     print(f'time to read array slices from CHUNCKED dataset: {time.time()-start:.03f}')
```